# How to select the first and last row relevant to an item in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following `events` tables that track events related to various items: when an item was created, when it was updated, and finally when it was deleted.

For example it would look like this:

| id | item_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | create |
| 2 | 2 | create |
| 3 | 1 | update |
| 4 | 1 | update |
| 5 | 2 | update |
| 6 | 1 | delete |
| 7 | 2 | update |
| 8 | 3 | create |

So in this table item 1 was created, then item 2 was created, then both items were updated multiple times. In the end item 1 was deleted, but item 2 is still there. Eventually item 3 was created and never modified.

I'm trying to create a query that would give me the first and last event for each item, so after running this query I would get this:

| id | item_id | first_event_type | last_event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | create | delete |
| 2 | 2 | create | update |
| 8 | 3 | create | NULL |

I've tried various queries, but didn't get much further than joining the table on itself, as I don't know how to express that the joined table should return the last result relevant to the current item_id.

Any idea if it is possible to do this with just one query?

(If that can make a difference I am using PostgresSQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select item_id,
    max(type) filter(where rn_asc = 1) as first_event_type,
    max(type) filter(where rn_desc = 1 and rn_asc > 1) as last_event_type
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by item_id order by id) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by item_id order by id desc) rn_desc
    from mytable t
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
group by item_id
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. I'm wondering, is the `where 1 in...` necessary, as the select should only select rn_asc/desc with value 1 anyway? Also if I understand correctly the purpose of `max(type)` is simply to allow applying a filter, and the aggregate itself is not relevant, is that correct? (Like I guess it could be `min(type)` and it would work the same?)

Comment: @laurent: `where 1 in (...)` is just a way to reduce the number of rows to process before aggregation, so that's an optimization somehow. And yes, your understanding is correct on how conditional aggregation works.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't support "first" and "last" aggregation functions.  But you can come close with `array_agg()`:

```
select item_id,
       (array_agg(type order by id))[1] as first_type,
       (array_agg(type order by id desc))[1] as last_type
from t
group by item_id;
```